# Is it possible to add filter,sort and group to TablePersoController in sapui5?

Tags: sapui5, personalization

I am trying to build Variant Managment and TablePersoController together in SAPUI5. I wonder if it is possible to add fields of filtering,sorting and grouping  to TablePersoController.

I found p13n dialog box to achieve this but it means i have to abandon TablePersoController for my project. I think i need TablePersoController to make a persistent user settings. So , i need an another solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can add a 2nd dialog named ViewSettingsDialog. It does exactly those 3 things. If you want all in one you may need to take a look at the smart table.

Comment: @Erch Smarttable looks simple but complicated inside :\ i will try to use ViewSettingsDialog , thanks

Comment: yea "simple", isn't simple to use : ) but its quite powerful

Comment: I actually tried it before but variant managment view gave me "Unable to load the data." when i open the view for Variant Managment dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Table personalization is used for setting which columns in a table are shown. P13n can also be used.
See the external Fiori design guidelines for an explanation of when to use these controls:
https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/overview-table-personalization/

Table Personalization is intended to allow the user to set the displayed/hidden columns. This is not intended for filters and sorting.
ViewSettings can be used to set filters, sort and group criteria.
P13n dialog allows tables with more than 20 columns to be personalized, for the ALV display and for complex queries.

The FilterBar/SmartFilterBar allows complicated queries to be specified: 
https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/filter-bar/ describes the use of a FilterBar.
(SmartFilterBar uses the OData Service to describe the fields used in the FilterBar.

Persistence of the settings is done with the launchpad, known as shellservices.